# Read multilines json file (non-JSONL) with Apache Beam in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I cannot manage to read input multiline JSON input files in a Apache Beam pipeline (coded in Python).

I understand that ReadFromFile with a JSON coder reads JSONL files but how to handle files with following format:

```
[{
  "name": "name1",
  "value": "val1"
},
{
  "name": "name2",
  "value": "val2"
}]
```

I cam across the `FileSystem` module which contains the `open()` function allows to read the entire file (not line by line) but this returns a file handle (as per the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.io.filesystem.html))

But what to do afterwards? This might not be the good way to do it, so any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing native to read JSON files.

However you can write a ParDo that takes a Filename and parses the file (outputing whatever you want from the file). In this ParDo you can use whatever libraries exist to parse a JSON file.

To generate the list of filepatterns:
In Beam Java, this can be done in Beam by using FileIO.match() and FileIO.readMatches to get a PCollection.

For python you will have to implement the match yourself unfortunately. You'll want to do a Create(filepattern), ParDo(expands the filepattern), reshuffle, ParDo(your ParDo that reads the file).

Comment: Thanks Lara. I ended up doing something very simple `beam.Create(json.loads(FileSystems.open(known_args.input).read()))`. But based on your answer, it looks too simple... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you just reading a single file? This seems to be reading it in the client and not on the workers. Is that the case?
My suggestion was based on if you had a lot of filepatterns you wanted to read. If it's just one, then it should be simpler.

Comment: Yes one single file. I does work with DirectRunner and on GCP as a custom template.